# Composition of Ordered Pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm doing math exercises from a Computer Science book and I am confused as to how the following result (from the solutions manual) is obtained:

Given the function f={(a,b), (a,c), (c,d), (a,a), (b,a)}

The composition of f with itself: f(f(x)) = {(a,a), (a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (b,a), (b,b), (b,c)}
.

By matching the y-values of the first function with the x-values of the second function, I managed to get all the pairs in the above answer accept for (b, b) and (b, c). Does anyone know what I've done wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: From the sixth line you mean that `(b,b)` and `(b,c)` shouldn't be in `fof`?

Comment: @Babak Yes that's what I initially thought. However the textbook's solutions include those pairs. I'm unsure how they obtained those pairs for FoF though.

Comment: $f$ is not a function. It is a relation. If $f$ were a function, since $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ and $(a,a)$ are all in $f$, this would mean that $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this relation's defined,  we see that $(a,b)\in f$ and $(b,a)\in f$ so $f(\color{red}a)=b$ and $f(b)=\color{red}a$ respectively. So $f(f(b))=f(\color{red}a)=b$. This means that $(b,b)\in f$.